# Confusion in calculating radiation pressure

Tags: thermal-radiation, radiation-pressure

As mentioned [here in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_pressure?wprov=sfla1) the net radiation pressure on a perfect reflective surface is $ {2I \over c}$
where $I$ is irradiance and $c$ is the speed of light

In case of a perfect  blackbody $I = σT^4$ so  $ P = {2σT^4 \over c}$ which differs by a factor of $2/3$  from ${4σT^4 \over 3c}$ that results from finding the relation between radiation pressure and energy density

where have I gone wrong here? Why these two results don't agree?

Answer (score 1):

They describe different things. $2I/c$ is the pressure is from light in one direction only. $\frac{4\sigma T^4}{3c}$ is for an isotropic photon gas where light travels in all directions.

The factor of $2/3$ comes from considering the geometry really really carefully. Consider a small flat surface surrounded by a large sphere at equilibrium. The pressure from a source on the sphere at an angle $\theta$ to the surface is given by

$$P=\cos^2\theta P_0,$$

where $P_0$ is the pressure if the radiation were normal to the sphere. One factor of $\cos\theta$ comes from the larger surface area that a beam would cover, lowering the intensity (i.e. Lambert's law). Another factor comes from the direction of the force, since we only want the normal component of the pressure and not any shear forces.

Integrating this over a hemisphere gives

$$P=\rho\int \cos^2\theta\sin\theta~d\theta d\phi=\frac{2\pi}{3}\rho$$

where $\rho$ is the pressure per steradian of the sphere coming from the sphere. Now lets think about emission. A perfect blackbody emits a total of $A\sigma T^4$ radiation, and has an angular dependence of $\cos\theta$ by Lambert's law, so you have

$$\sigma T^4=I_0 \int \cos \theta\sin\theta~d\theta d\phi =\pi I_0,$$

where $I_0$ is the maximum intensity per steradian of emission, per area of the sphere. Since all the emitting surfaces are perpendicular to the direction of propagation, the emission is always at its maximum, $I_0$.

Now consider a small sector of the sphere with solid angle $\Omega$ and compute how much power from that sector reaches our small flat surface. The area of this sector is $\Omega R^2$. The solid angle of the small flat surface is $A/R^2$. ($A$ is the area of the small flat surface and $R$ is the distance from the surface to the sector of the sphere.) So the power transmitted is $I_0A\Omega$, so the intensity of the transmitted light is just

$$I_0\Omega = \frac{\sigma T^4}{\pi}\Omega$$

Then $\rho$, the pressure per steradian of the sphere (using the equation for the perfect reflecting surface you have) is given by

$$\rho=\frac{1}{\Omega}\frac{2\frac{\sigma T^4}{\pi}\Omega}{c}=2\frac{\sigma T^4}{\pi c}$$

and so the total pressure is

$$P=\frac{2\pi}{3}\rho=\frac{4}{3}\frac{\sigma T^4}{c}$$

If this was too involved, the idea is that you get a factor of $2$ from Lambert's $\cos\theta$ dependence of the intensity, and you get a factor of $1/3$ from the $\cos^2\theta$ dependence on the pressure.